# SimpleXML - HTML: element within common text

Tags: php, html, simplexml

I'm parsing a document HTML using DOM -> SimpleXML:

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($this->resource->get());
$html = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
```

And wanna load this piece:

```
<p>
    Some text here <strong class="wanna-attributes-too">with strong element!</strong>.
    But there can be even <b>bold</b> tag and many others.
</p>
```

Then I want *do something* and export it; but inner tags are parsed as child nodes of `<p>` - that is formally right, but how can I reconstruct original document? Is there some library which can handle tags inside text values?

How about browsers as that is common case?

Thanks

// p.s. I *CAN* parse documents with nodes within text, that *ISN'T* problem; problem is that nodes lost their positions in original text

**Update v1.0**
Ok, solution can be encapsulating every node, which has nodes and value at the same time.

Updated question can be - how to get *raw* node value from simple_xml?

From previous HTML fragment I want something like this:

```php
echo $nodeParagraph->rawValue;
```

and output will be

```
Some text here <strong class="wanna-attributes-too">with strong element!</strong>.
But there can be even <b>bold</b> tag and many others.
```

**Update v2.0**
My bad - SimpleXML node has saveXML (alis to asXML) which does what I want. Sorry for a noise. I'll post answer when I build working test.

Comment: I would say that it loses its position because that's how XML is structured. After some googling I found [W3 XML Data Model](http://www.w3.org/XML/Datamodel.html) where the part about linking nodes may be of some interest.

Comment: I know that it is its characterics (I've node, its childs or value, but - formally - not both). But I must be able to load given structure (with messed nodes inside value) to export it back again... formally - finding solution, how to build template engine (I know, there are many, ....).

Comment: So if you check out the link i sent you, then you could temporarily parse the text into <p> tags and break the tag when it hits another tag. So it would look something like: `<p>
    <p id="x1">Some text here</p> <strong id="#x1" class="wanna-attributes-too">with strong element!</strong></p> ` etc...

Comment: @jzasnake Is seems like interesting idea... yes, this can be solution, I must test it; thanks for pushing me back to the way

Comment: Can you give an example of the current code which has the *wrong* output? Just importing into SimpleXML itself won't change the structure any, so just writing `$html->asXML()` should give it back to you unchanged. [Demo of doing just that](https://3v4l.org/Vis0P). The key presumably is in the rather vague "do something" in your initial description; if you tell us *what* you want to do, maybe we can help...

Comment: As for looking for other libraries, you're already using one - the DOM. It's not as Simple as SimpleXML, but one of the differences is that it treats each piece of text as a "node" in its own right, so the `<p>` tag in this example would have 5 children - text, `<strong>`, text, `<b>`, text.

Comment: @IMSoP You are right, asXML works as expected - even if SimpleXMLNode doesn't return content from inner tags, asXML works good; thanks for reply :)

Comment: Yep, the thing to remember is that SimpleXML doesn't *represent* the XML document, it is *an API for examining and manipulating it*. So when you cast a `SimpleXMLElement` to a string, or echo it, you are actually running an internal function which loops through the children of the node, outputting only text and CDATA nodes; but the other nodes are still there, in the right order. Similarly, when you run `->children()`, you get all the *non-text* children, but the text hasn't been deleted, it's just not returned by that function. You can even go back to the DOM with `dom_import_simplexml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @jzasnake pointed out, nice solution is to do this:

sample (input):

```
<p>
    Some text here <strong class="wanna-attributes-too">with strong element!</strong>.
    But there can be even <b>bold</b> tag and many others.
</p>
```

this outputs something like this in DOM:

- p

  - strong
  - b

where text is in incorret order (if you later wanna reconstruct it).

Solution can be eveloping every text into its own node (*notice `<value>` tags*):

```
<p>
    <value>Some text here </value><strong class="wanna-attributes-too">with strong element!</strong><value>.
    But there can be even </value><b>bold</b><value> tag and many others.</value>
</p>
```

markup is a bit more talkative, but look at this:

- p

  - value
  - strong

    - value
  - value
  - b

    - value
  - value

Everything is preserved, so you are able to reconstruct original document as is.